Prove that $l^\infty$ is complete, The discussion on convergence.
Consider the normed space
$(l^\infty, \|\cdot\|) = \{u = \{u_n\}{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{C} \text{ such that } \|u\| := \sup{n \in \mathbb{N}} |u_n|\}.$
I attempted to prove that $(l^\infty, \|\cdot\|)$ is complete as following, but encountered several problems towards the end. Please provide a solution.
Let  $u^n = (u^n_1, u^n_2, \ldots)$  and assume that $\{u^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in  $l^\infty$ , so we have
$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that for all } m, n \geq N, \Rightarrow \|u^m - u^n\| < \varepsilon.$
Fix  $k \in \mathbb{N}$ . Then, we have
$|u^m_k - u^n_k| \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |u^m_k - u^n_k| = \|u^m - u^n\| < \varepsilon$,
which means that $\{u^n_k\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in  $K$ . Since  $K = \mathbb{C}$  or  $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, the limit  $u_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} u^n_k \in K$  exists. Now, let  $u = \{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  and show that  $u \in l^\infty $ and $ |u^n - u| \to 0 $ as  $n \to \infty$ .
Showing that  $u \in l^\infty$  is straightforward by using the boundedness of Cauchy sequences in  $K$ , so I will omit it.
Next, I will show that  $\|u^n - u\| \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty$ , but here is where the problem arises. Since  $\{u^n\}$  is a Cauchy sequence, we have
$|u^m - u^n| < \varepsilon $  for   $m, n \geq N$.  For any  $k \in \mathbb{N}$ , the inequality  $|u^m_k - u^n_k| < \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |u^m_k - u^n_k| = |u^m - u^n|$  holds. Therefore, we obtain the following:
$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists N > 0 \text{ such that for all } m, n \geq N, \Rightarrow |u^m_k - u^n_k| < \varepsilon.$
At this point, I tried to conclude that  $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |u^m_k - u_k| < \varepsilon$  by letting  $n \to \infty$ , using the fact that $ |u^m_k - u_k| < \varepsilon$ , but the uniformity over  $k$  is lost when taking the limit as  $n$  goes to infinity, making it difficult to justify taking the supremum at the end.
To clarify this issue, let’s rewrite it using the $\varepsilon$-$N$ method:
Since  $u^n_k \to u_k$  as  $n \to \infty$ , we have
$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N_k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that for all } n \geq N_k, |u^n_k - u_k| < \varepsilon.$
Let  $\tilde{N} = \max\{N, N_k\}$ . For  $n \geq \tilde{N}$ ,
$|u^n_k - u_k| = |u^n_k - u^{\tilde{N}}_k + u^{\tilde{N}}_k - u_k| \leq |u^n_k - u^{\tilde{N}}_k| + |u^{\tilde{N}}_k - u_k| < 2\varepsilon.$
However, $\tilde{N}$ still depends on  $k$ .
To resolve this problem, do I need to use a different approach? Or is there a way to address and justify my concerns? I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

At "Therefore, we obtain the following:" you got the order of quantifiers wrong: $\forall \epsilon>0$ $ \exists N$ such that $\forall k$ and all $m,n>N$ ..... Then $n\to\infty$, $\sup$ over $k$.

You have shown that $u_k^n$ is convergent for any $k$ and denoted its limit by $u_k.$ For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N_\varepsilon$ such that $\|u_n-u_m\|<\varepsilon $ for $n,m>  N_\varepsilon$. Thus $$|u_k^n-u_k^m|\le \|u^n-u^m\|<\varepsilon\quad n,m>  N_\varepsilon $$ Taking the limit when $m\to \infty$  yields $$|u_k^n-u_k|\le \varepsilon,\ n> N_\varepsilon$$ Thus $$\|u^n-u\|\le \varepsilon,\ n> N_\varepsilon\quad (*)$$ It means in particular that $u-u^{N_\varepsilon+1}\in \ell^\infty,$ hence $u=(u-u^{N_\varepsilon+1})+u^{N_\varepsilon+1}\in \ell^\infty.$ The condition $(*)$, applied for any $\varepsilon>0,$  implies that $u^n\to u$ in $ \ell^\infty.$
